# Get rendered bounds of a view in viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I've been searching for help on this all day but I can't find an answer.

I have a subview in which I am drawing a rectangle, the rectangle is framed by the subview so I need to know the size of the subview as adjusted by autolayout to correctly frame it.  I can't find a way of doing this from `ViewDidLoad()`, so that the rectangle is correctly rendered at start-up.  I have tried the following:

1. Using `dayView.setNeedsLayout()` followed by `dayView.layoutIfNeeded()` before I draw the rectangle in `viewDidLoad()` but a check either side of these statements shows the dayView.bounds unchanged.
2. Drawing the view from `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, which works, but results in my rectangle being drawn 5 times as `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is called for every subview (I have 5 of them) that is redrawn (the relevant subview containing the rectangle is redrawn on call 4 of 5) - this seems wasteful of resources, surely there is a better way?
3. Drawing the view twice within `ViewDidLoad()`, hoping the first forced draw will cause the view to be resized, so the second draw will have access to the new bounds after the first draw (desperate I know, but it still doesn't work).

I hope someone can help.

```
func drawGradient(object: UIView, rect: CGRect, slackX: Int, gradWidth: Int, yPos: Int) -> Void {
    // the rectangle width and height set to fit within view with x & y border.

    let gradientView = UIView(frame: rect)
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    gradient.frame = gradientView.frame
    gradient.colors = getDayGradientLocations().gradientCol
    gradient.locations = getDayGradientLocations().gradientLoc
    dayView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

    let civilDawn = getTimeAsProportionOfDay(time: tides.civilDawn) * Double(rect.height) + Double(yPos)
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: slackX, y: Int(civilDawn)))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: slackX + Int(rect.width), y: Int(civilDawn)))

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = CGFloat(2)

    let civilDusk = getTimeAsProportionOfDay(time: tides.civilDusk) * Double(rect.height) + Double(yPos)
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: slackX, y: Int(civilDusk)))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: slackX + Int(rect.width), y: Int(civilDusk)))
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = CGFloat(2)

    object.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    drawLabel(object: object, rect: rect, slackX: slackX, offset: 15, time: tides.civilDawn)
    drawLabel(object: object, rect: rect, slackX: slackX, offset: -15, time: tides.civilDusk)
}
```

[image: gradient drawing]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. If you are adjusting a view’s `frame` in your view controller, the right place to do this is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Yes, this is called a number of times, but it generally doesn’t have any observable impact on performance.

   I wouldn't advise any of those extremely brittle techniques of `setNeedsLayout`, `layoutIfNeeded`, or `DispatchQueue.main.async` inside `viewDidLoad`. The `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is the right place if you’re going to do this in the view controller.
2. Generally, if doing custom subview drawing and layout of subviews, you do this in the [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) of the view, rather than in any of the view controller methods.

   Likewise, if you're doing any manual drawing, you’d put that in the `UIView` subclass (or any of the relevant `CALayer` subclasses), not the view controller.
3. Even better, rather than adjusting frames manually, it’s better to let the auto layout system handle this for you if you can. If you find yourself manually adjusting a `frame`, there are generally better patterns.

   FWIW, you can define a container view’s constraints to be based upon the size (or intrinsic size) of its subviews (and set the content-hugging and compression-resistance of the relevant views). We often think of auto-layout as a top-down engine, but it works both ways.

If you show us your “drawing” code and/or a screen snapshot or two, we can probably offer more concrete counsel.

Comment: Thanks Rob, this is helpful.  In hindsight, I should have created a subview for my drawing and used the auto layout to do the hard work of resizing but I, instead, created a rectangle programatically positioned it within a subview as a CALayer and added it with that as a sublayer.  I have added some of my drawing code above, please feel free to critique - I am still learning.

Answer (score -1):

Got to main thread in viewDidLoad and Perform action will resolve your issue

```
         DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                // here you can add anything it will have proper frame
            }
```

Comment: Wow!  Yes, that has resolved the situation and my views are updated correctly with no need to call viewDidLayoutSubViews().  Thanks very much, can you explain why this code resolves the problem please?